# How do you connect your application framework (Django/Rails, etc.) to a back-end written in some other language?

Tags: django

If there are parts of my application which are very memory intensive and algorithmic, I would want to implement these in C or Java. What would be the best way to connect this code to my Django/(Rails, Merb etc.) web application?

Comment: This is a programming problem, and thus belongs on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to interact with it and what you are most comfortable with. I usually wrap the functionality up in a nice HTTP interface so I can access it from Python (or any other language). Pretty much every language has HTTP libraries and it's pretty easy to make a small REST API. Once it's available over HTTP, it also allows you to use standard HTTP tools for debugging, caching, and load-balancing. For heavier duty processing that can benefit from a queue, Celery/RabbitMQ are powerful and RabbitMQ can be interfaced with from quite a few languages. [ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org/) can also be a very flexible and lightweight approach.

As an aside, if you the algorithmically intense parts of your application can be formulated into vector operations, check out [NumPy](https://numpy.org/). You may not have to leave Python

Comment: Would the second non-python http interface be resource-expensive?

Comment: Depends on what you need it to do and how you build it. The overhead of HTTP itself is fairly minimal. You're going to have to figure out what tradeoffs are acceptable in your specific situation. The upside to using a network protocol between the pieces is that if one turns out to be very resource-intensive, you could run just that piece on a separate machine from the rest of your web app.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried finding/writing a message/instruction queue processing interface for your C/Java code? That way you can pass jobs from your webapp to the message/instruction queue, where your C/Java code would pick up messages, and process them.

For Django, you have the option of using something like [Celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/).

Comment: Celery runs on RabbitMQ which has implementations across many languages as well, java, python, c, ruby

Comment: Checked out celery. Should work out with what I have in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Python talking to C/C++, you can use:

[Extending Python with C or C++](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html)

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html#python.quickstart)

The idea in the above 2 solutions is that you will write your memory intensive code in C/C++ and then invoke them from within Python.